# Merge two lists while removing duplicates

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk, busybox

I have an embedded linux system using Busybox (OpenWRT) - so commands are limited.  I have two files that look like:

first file

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
mmmmmm
nnnnnn
```

second file

```
mmmmmm
nnnnnn
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

**I need to merge these 2 lists into 1 file, and remove the duplicates.**  I don't have diff (space is limited) so we get to use the great `awk`, `sed`, and `grep` (or other tools that might be included in a standard Busybox instance).  Going to a merge file like:

```
command1 > mylist.merge 
command2 mylist.merge > originallist
```

is totally ok.  It doesn't have to be a single-line command.

Currently defined functions in the instance of Busybox that I am using (default OpenWRT):
        [, [[, arping, ash, awk, basename, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, clear, cmp,
        cp, crond, crontab, cut, date, dd, df, dirname, dmesg, du, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, find,
        free, fsync, grep, gunzip, gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostid, hwclock, id, ifconfig, init, insmod, kill,
        killall, klogd, less, ln, lock, logger, logread, ls, lsmod, md5sum, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mktemp, mount,
        mv, nc, netmsg, netstat, nice, nslookup, ntpd, passwd, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, pkill,
        poweroff, printf, ps, pwd, reboot, reset, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, sed, seq, sh, sleep, sort,
        start-stop-daemon, strings, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd, tail, tar, tee, telnet, telnetd, test,
        time, top, touch, tr, traceroute, true, udhcpc, umount, uname, uniq, uptime, vconfig, vi, watchdog, wc,
        wget, which, xargs, yes, zcat

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
mmmmmm
nnnnnn
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

will do what you want.

Additional Documentation: [uniq](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) [sort](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)

Comment: busybox sort supports the unique flag `-u`.

Comment: @Thor: oooh cheers that's not a switch I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 22):

In just one command without any pipe :

```
sort -u FILE1 FILE2
```

search

> Suppress duplicate lines

-> http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

Comment: which one is better for very large files? 
`sort file1 file2 file3 file4 | uniq` or `sort -u file1 file2 file3 file4`

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file_1 file_2
```

Comment: I saw that it made a difference which argument came first. Otherwise great solution, thanks.

Comment: It boggles my mind that if someone posts e.g. a Python solution to a problem, people often request an explanation of the code, but whenever it's awk, which relatively few people understand, it's fine to just leave it as is. :)

Answer (score 3):

The files on your question are sorted.
If the source files are indeed sorted, you can uniq and merge in one step:

```
sort -um file1 file2 > mylist.merge
```

For numeric sort (not alphanumeric), use:

```
sort -num file1 file2 > mylist.merge
```

That could **not** be done in-place (redirected to one source file).

If the files are not sorted, sort them (this sort could be done in place, using the sort option `-o`. However, the whole file needs to be loaded into memory):

```
sort -uo file1 file1
sort -uo file2 file2
sort -um file1 file2 > mylist.merge
mv mylist.merge originallist
```

That would be faster than the simpler "one command line" to sort all:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u >mylist.merge
```

However, this line could be useful for small files.

Answer (score 2):

To sort according to some key column use following :

```
awk '!duplicate[$1,$2,$3]++' file_1 file_2
```

here consider first, second and third column as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If using variables instead of files:

```
sort -u <(printf '%s\n' "${list1}") <(printf '%s\n' "${list2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(!seen[$0]++)print $0}' file1 file2
```

output

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
mmmmmm
nnnnnn
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
final_list=[]
g=open('file1','r')
for vb in g:
    if vb.strip() not in final_list:
        final_list.append(vb.strip())
g.close()        
b=open('file2','r')
for hj in b:
    if hj.strip() not in final_list:
        final_list.append(hj.strip())

b.close()
print "\n".join(final_list)
```

output

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
mmmmmm
nnnnnn
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```